# Why do some programs running from Terminal using '&' close when Terminal does and others do not?

Tags: command-line, sudo, execute-command

I was just wondering, for instance when I launch `qtox` with:

```
qtox &
```

And then close Terminal, `qtox` closes with it. However when running `etherape` using:

```
sudo etherape &
```

Closing Terminal doesn't close or cause any problem to Etherape. And among different applications there is different behaviour, some close when Terminal does, others do not, how come? Why do some close when others don't? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: Could it be that you open a terminal, you run qtox, you close terminal, all you !!
But the second goes you open terminal, sudo runs etherape, now you close your terminal, but sudo keeps running till sudo closes?

Comment: Well, if you don't want `qtox` exiting when you close the terminal you can always run it with `nohup qtox &`.

Comment: @Terrance: Well, in this question I was specifically asking why, not how... That would be [my other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704322/how-to-keep-programs-running-that-are-executed-using-and-close-when-terminal)... :)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Ah, good point.  My bad.  =)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When you close a terminal the terminal sends a SIGHUP signal to the shell; the shell, in turn, sends a SIGHUP signal to all its children process groups, which include backgrounded process groups;

How each single process will react to the signal is entirely up to the process: if the process didn't define a handler for the signal and tell the kernel (via some syscall such as [`signal()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) or [`sigaction()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction)) that it wishes to handle it, the kernel executes the default handler for the signal, which in case of a SIGHUP signal consists in terminating the process.

However, when you run a command with `sudo`, the UID of the `sudo` process and its child process is set to `0` (root); in general, unless the UID of the process sending the signal is `0` (root) or the same as the target process, the kernel dismisses the signal (i.e.: a process can't send signals to a process owned by another user, unless the process sending the signal is owned by root); that's why an user-run process such as the Bash instance run by the terminal can't SIGHUP a `sudo` process and, ultimately, closing a terminal doesn't affect a process started with `sudo`.

Comment: And that's why we need `nohup` in front of those commands that do close with SIGHUP :) Upgoated

Comment: I *think* there's nothing magic about `sudo`. `sudo` just runs command as another user and you can't send signal to other users' processes. See `man  2 kill`.

Comment: @el.pescado So is `sudo` some kind of poor man's `nohup`?

Comment: @el.pescado Indeed. My answer was edited by OP as he realized he ran the command using sudo, it was different before;  I clarified that point.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If you want, but I'd highly refrain from running a command that doesn't require `sudo` with `sudo` for its `nohup` side-effect, considered all the other downsides.

Comment: @Serg we don't need `nohup`, it creates unneeded `nohup.out` files after it. Rather use `disown` builtin command.

Comment: @Ruslan  If one redirects output streams to `/dev/null` , nohup won't create the  `nohup.out` file.   Example: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13602644/  There is always a solution

Comment: @Serg of course it's a solution, just more to type ;)